# url_for for class-based views in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a class-based Admin view:

```
class All_RDPs(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return 'ok1'
    @expose('/test')
    def testindex(self):
        return 'ok2'
```

which is registered with Flask-Admin like so:

```
admin.add_view(All_RDPs(name='dep_rdp'))
```

and then is viewable from the browser like so:

```
http://localhost/admin/all_rdps/
http://localhost/admin/all_rdps/test
```

the question is:

1. how do I specify the URL for this class instead of the default generated name `all_rdps`?
2. how do I use `url_for` to generate urls for these endpoints? `url_for('admin.All_RDPs.testindex')`, `url_for('admin.All_RDPs')` don't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> You can override the endpoint name by passing endpoint parameter to
>   the view class constructor:
>
> ```
> admin = Admin(app)
> admin.add_view(MyView(endpoint='testadmin'))
> ```
>
> In this case, you can generate links by concatenating the view method
>   name with an endpoint:
>
> ```
> url_for('testadmin.index')
> ```
>
> If you don't override the endpoint name, the lower-case class name can
>   be used for generating URLs, like in:
>
> ```
> url_for('myview.index')
> ```
>
> For model-based views the rules differ - the model class name should
>   be used if an endpoint name is not provided. The ModelView also has
>   these endpoints by default: .index_view, .create_view, and .edit_view.
>   So, the following urls can be generated for a model named "User":
>
> ```
> # List View
> url_for('user.index_view')
>
> # Create View (redirect back to index_view)
> url_for('user.create_view', url=url_for('user.index_view'))
>
> # Edit View for record #1 (redirect back to index_view)
> url_for('user.edit_view', id=1, url=url_for('user.index_view'))
> ```

Source: [Flask-Admin quickstart](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/doc/quickstart.rst)